# data loss when file is transfer from server to client using stream in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file, network-programming, transfer

**server side**

```
stream.BeginWrite(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, 
       new AsyncCallback(CompleteWrite), stream);
```

**client side**

```
int tot = s.Read(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
```

I have used TCPClient,TCPlistener classes

clientData is a byte array.Size of ClientData is 2682 in server side.I have used NetworkStream class to write data

but in client side received data contains only 1642 bytes.I have used stream class to read data in client side

What's wrong?

Comment: There is 2 ways to solve this problem Send the size of the data first and read that (Look at the BitConverter), or read until you read 0 bytes (0 = EOF)

Comment: I have checked with size of data.I use the ReadWholeArray() method to read stream untill the size of sent data but after reading 1642 bytes the next call to read next remaining data stucked.then the program is not responding

Comment: Then you should double-check if you're really sending all 2682 bytes on the server side. Do you call `stream.EndWrite` from your CompleteWrite method?

Answer (score 4):

The Read method is permitted to return fewer bytes than you requested. You need to call Read repeatedly until you have received the number of bytes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to read properly from a stream:

```
public static void ReadWholeArray (Stream stream, byte[] data)
{
int offset=0;
int remaining = data.Length;
while (remaining > 0)
{
    int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);
    if (read <= 0)
        throw new EndOfStreamException 
            (String.Format("End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
    remaining -= read;
    offset += read;
 }
}
```

You may want to Write the length of the file into the stream first (say as an int)
eg,

### server side:

```
server.Write(clientData.Length)
server.Write(clientData);
```

### client side:

```
 byte[] size = new byte[4];                
 ReadWholeArray(stream, size);
 int fileSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(size, 0);
 byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileSize];
 ReadWholeArray(stream, fileBytes);
```

see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html for more info on reading from streams.

Comment: In server side coding the object server is which class? Beacause I use NetworkStream class object with method Write for this code it tells "No overload for method 'Write' takes '1' arguments".So Please tell server object belongs to which class

Comment: Just use BeginWrite like you do in your original code sample, or use Write(clientData, 0, clientData.Length), assuming clientData is your byte[] array